# Как скрыть папку?

Tags: android, файлы

Необходимо скрыть папку, чтобы пользователь не смог в неё залезть и удалить там картинки, которые необходимы для приложения как ресурсы.

Некоторые могут написать, что храни ресурсы в папке res и не дури головы, но мне необходима папка, в которой будут храниться картинки, которые скачал пользователь, также есть БД, в которой хранятся пути к этим картинкам. Я не хочу, чтобы слишком любопытный пользователь удалил картинки при помощи файлового менеджера и потом это повлияло на работу приложения.

Есть и другой путь, как я думаю, можно тупо, если по нужному пути в БД нету картинки, не выводить её, или если пользователь её переместил куда-нибудь, то использовать **FileObserver**, но всё же хочется дополнительно оградить пользователя от самого себя. Нашёл [инфу](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#isHidden()), что скрытыми файлами являются те, которые запускаются с именем, содержащим в начале символ точки "."

Также, раз уже завёл этот вопрос, хочу поинтересоваться, где удобнее хранить картинки, а точнее, как их сохранять в подпапке приложения **data** или **obb** или ещё какая-нибудь папка предназначенная для таких целей, т.е. **функция**, которая будет возвращать путь к этой папке.

Comment: Хранить во внутренней памяти: context.getFilesDir()

Comment: Если Вам нужно, чтобы пользователь гарантированно не мог удалить файлы, храните их на своем сервере.

Comment: В данном случае, это нужно не мне, а самому пользователю, но иногда нужно уберечь пользователя от самого себя

Comment: >Нашёл инфу, что скрытыми файлами являются те, которые запускаются с именем, содержащим в начале символ точки "."

Это "пять"

Comment: > В данном случае это нужно не мне, а самому пользователю, но иногда нужно уберечь пользователя от самого себя.

Тогда делайте бекап в его гугловый аккаунт (google drive) и если нужно, пользователь может откатить.

Comment: Barmaley, ссылку в студию, я не могу найти вашу "пять"

Comment: Кстати, хранение в res не поможет, я могу вытащить ресурсы любого приложения, используя PackageManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файлы и папки с точкой в имени можно увидеть сторонним файл менеджером. Можно хранить ресурсы в папке приложения (путь выдаётся командой  `getFilesDir()`), но там не рекомендуется хранить больше одного мегабайта, так как это папка на системном диске и память может кончится.
В файл obb записывать нельзя, только считывать.

Можешь сделать свою фичу: например, в папке `/sdcard/android/data/you.package.name/` хранить архив zip, защищенный паролем, и через приложение открывать его на запись и добавлять туда файлы, то есть максимум, что сможет юзер, не зная пароль, - удалить весь архив.

Comment: Данный путь всегда существует, и имя его неизменно и на всех аппаратах одинаково? Если на каждом аппарате разное, то прошу дать метод, который вызывает данный путь, или хотя бы /sdcard/android или его подобие

Comment: Данный путь доступен, только если вставлена карта памяти. Путь может отличаться, а точнее первая директория, на нектороых девайсах это sdcard, на других - extsd и т.д.... Но текущий путь к сдкарте можно получить. Вот универсальный метод, вернет папку на сдкарте,  а если она не доступна, вернет папку на внутренней памяти http://pastebin.com/2LQ5bMdC